# Remove lines starting with pattern A or B, except when they contain pattern C or D

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like this:

```
1 foo
1 bar
1 someOtherString
2 contains bar and more
2 test
3 contains a random string
4 some other string
2 don't remove this line bar
2 but remove this line
14 keep this line
21 and also this line
7 bar
```

From this file, i want to get this file:

```
1 foo
1 bar
2 contains bar and more
3 contains a random string
4 some other string
2 don't remove this line bar
14 keep this line
21 and also this line
7 bar
```

Basically:

- keep all lines that do not start with "1 " nor "2 "
- keep all lines that contain either "foo" or "bar"
- remove all other lines
- keep the order intact

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate what you already tried and where you faced problems. That way you can avoid receiving solutions that you already know won't work.

Comment: Do you need to do this with grep or are you open to other standard tools? Also, in the _actual_ use case: (1) Is the "exclusion" pattern also actually the first "word" and not simply the start of the line (otherwise, `14` and `21` would be removed in your example), and (2) can the pattern that would mandate keeping the line be part of the first "word" (e.g. is a line starting with `1foo` possible)?

Comment: @AdminBee I don't care which tool, as long as it works. The exclusion pattern is not "1" but "1 " (that is why "14" should not match). To (2): No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the data in a file called `file`. The requirements to achieve your example results are slightly different to the statements you posted:

- Keep all lines in `file` that match either of these criteria:

  - do not start with `1`  nor `2`  (that's a digit followed by a space)
  - contain `foo` or `bar`
- Remove all other lines
- Keep the order intact

This can be expressed in `perl` by matching two expressions and printing the line (in sequence) if either matched:

```
perl -ne '( !/^(1 |2 )/ or /foo|bar/ ) and print' file
```

As an afterthought, this entire requirement can be expressed slightly differently:

- For each line in turn

  - Print the line if it doesn't start with `1`  or `2`
  - Print the line if it contains `foo` or `bar`

And this maps to `awk` really conveniently:

```
awk '!/^(1 |2 )/ || /foo/ || /bar/' file
```

In both cases (`perl` and `awk`) the RE `^(1 |2 )` can be simplified by bringing out the common factor and rewriting it as `^[12]` :

```
perl -ne '( !/^[12] / or /foo|bar/ ) and print' file
awk '!/^[12] / || /foo/ || /bar/' file
```

Comment: Maybe `/^(1|2) /` for a more concise version?

Comment: @terdon I preferred keeping the pattern described by the OP, but yes in my real code I'd have simplified the common element

Comment: What is different in my listed requirements and the ones you listed?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 the way your requirements are read is with an implied _and_ between them: "_keep all lines that do not start with "1 " nor "2 "_" and then "_keep all lines that contain either "foo" or "bar"_" and then "_remove all other lines_". The example (thank you for that) shows that your first two requirements are actually to be joined with _or_.

Comment: @roaima I still don't see a difference, of course you can formulate it differently but for me this two requirements are the same. Anyway, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^[12]\>/ { /foo/ !{ /bar/ !d; }; }' file
1 foo
1 bar
2 contains bar and more
3 contains a random string
4 some other string
2 don't remove this line bar
14 keep this line
21 and also this line
7 bar
```

The above uses `sed` to test whether each line starts with either `1` or `2` followed by a non-word character (you may replace `\>` by a single space if you wish).  If it does not, then the line is printed.  If it does, the line is tested for the substring `foo`. If that substring exists, the line is printed.  If it does not exist, a similar test is made for `bar`, and the line is printed if it matches and deleted if it doesn't.

Reading the logic from the `d` backwards: The line is deleted if it doesn't match `bar` and does not match `foo` but starts with `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep( !/^ [ 1 | 2 ] \s / | / foo | bar / );'
```

OR

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep( { !/^ [ 1 | 2 ] \s /} | / foo | bar / );'
```

OR

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep( (none /^ [ 1 | 2 ] \s /) | / foo | bar / );'
```

Sample Input:

```
1 foo
1 bar
1 someOtherString
2 contains bar and more
2 test
3 contains a random string
4 some other string
2 don't remove this line bar
2 but remove this line
14 keep this line
21 and also this line
7 bar
```

Sample Output:

```
1 foo
1 bar
2 contains bar and more
3 contains a random string
4 some other string
2 don't remove this line bar
14 keep this line
21 and also this line
7 bar
```

Above is a rough translation of @roaima's Perl5  code, although in Raku this is properly a `grep` operation. In Raku, you can test for the absence of a pattern using either the `!` negation operator (shown above with/without a surrounding `{...}` codeblock), or using a `none` junction (related to `Sets` in Raku).

You may note the inclusion of a `\s` character in the regex. That's because undeclared (`\s`) whitespace and/or *"...unquoted whitespace in a regex is generally ignored..."* by default in Raku, making for more readable code. See links below.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Sigspace
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

We can use lookarounds profitably for such kind of multi-condition searches:

```
$ grep -vP '^(?=[12]\h)(?!.*(?:foo|bar))' file
```

---

Python can be used with it's re module to perform matching and filtering based on the search result status.

```
python3 -c 'import re, sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  print(*filter(lambda x: re.match(r"(?![12]\s)",x) or re.search(r"foo|bar",x),f),sep="",end="")
' file
```